# SocialMediaData related functions don't save authentication data

Tags: security, social-media

Is there any way to stop `SocialMediaData` and `ServiceExecute` from making me re-authenticate every time?

For example, say I have my *Twitter* or *Instagram* key saved, how can I use `ServiceConnect` to programmatically connect to the service using my key, so I don't have to type it into a prompt like this:

[image]