# How can I pass authentication credentials to ServiceConnect["GoogleCustomSearch"]?

Tags: webservices, serviceexecute

Is it possible to connect to the GoogleCustomSearch service without entering the authentication credentials in the popup dialog every time?

Comment: Related: [80422](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80422/731)

Answer (score 3):

When the popup for the API key and search engine ID comes up, there is a checkbox to save the information for next time.  If you don't see this, try using ServiceDisconnect["GoogleCustomSearch"] and then reconnect again.

Comment: Yes I tried that checkbox, but without success: Even if checked, the dialog pops up every time.

Answer (score 1):

Do two things before entering GoogleCustomSearch:

1. Navigate to https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview. Click the blue button GET A KEY. Click the symbol to the right of the Google Custom Search API Key and paste it into the dialog box field of GoogleCustomSearch.

[image]

2. Navigate to https://cse.google.com/cse/setup/basic. Log in, if required. Just fill in the basics tap. Your new search engine id is presented with an button to the right named Paste to the clipboard or so. It is named Search engine ID. It is followed by the public URL of the new defined search engine. Select Your personal choice of setting and select the to be searched web site for more performance.

[image]